# How can I increment the index of an array that is in quotes?

Tags: powershell

I can get the individual lines of a text file in powershell by indexing surround them with quotes by sub-expression

```
$textFile = Get-Content "myText.txt"
$i = 0
"$($textFile[$i])"
```

This will output the first line from the test file. But when I try to increment the index, it's not being passed to the variable when I call it, and still outputs the first line.

```
$i++                   # value is now 1
"$($textFile[$i])"     # value is still at the first index

$i++                   # value is now 2
"$($textFile[$i])"     # value is still at the first index  

$i++                   # value is now 3
"$($textFile[$i])"     # value is still at the first index
```

The reason I'm keeping the variable in quotes is because that one line of the text file part of a bigger string that I can execute

```
while ($i -lt $textFile.count) 
{    
    $remote = "Enter-PSSession -ComputerName`", $(textFile[$i])"
    Invoke-Expression $remote 
    $global:i++
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. There is a typo in your last block of code however, `textfile` is missing the preceeding `$`. Furthermore the way you construct the string for `$remote` (even with the above missing `$` fixed) produces an unusable string. Why not use `$remote = 'Enter-PSSession -ComputerName {0}' -f $textFile[$i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Was able to produce the desired outcome by using a foreach loop instead of a while loop:

```
foreach ($line in $textFile) 
{    
    $remote = "Enter-PSSession -ComputerName`" $line"
    Invoke-Expression $remote
}
```